# Remove "stop sharing" bar/popup

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I use the below code to remove *"stop sharing"* bar/popup

```
screenStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
```

Is there any other way to remove *"stop sharing"* bar/popup?
Can I use chrome instance to remove that bar/popup from desktop?

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd like to change that if it works?

Comment: Actually, I am using tokbox js and recently I have added camera-filter API(not supported officially by tokbox) to share(change stream in runtime) PDF template with other users, all working well but when I stop screen share "stop sharing" bar not close.

Comment: I have also tried above code but above code also not working because camera filter API overrides getUserMedia function of webrtc.